How to write to different files based on value of list of dicts and concat the for loop and three list of dicts
First of all, I'm sorry if the question is too long. I tried to include the least data, but that was I could add.
These are the lists I have:
products_income = [
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 2, 'product': 'A', 'monthly_income': 370},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 1, 'product': 'B', 'monthly_income': 215},
    {'client_group': 'C', 'count': 3, 'product': 'C', 'monthly_income': 495},
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 2, 'product': 'D', 'monthly_income': 304},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 1, 'product': 'E', 'monthly_income': 110},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 2, 'product': 'F', 'monthly_income': 560},
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 1, 'product': 'G', 'monthly_income': 196},
    ]

client_package = [
    {'client_group': 'A', 'total_income': 870},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'total_income': 885},
    {'client_group': 'C', 'total_income': 495}
]

client_group_user_counts = {
    'A': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5'], # 5 users
    'B': ['user21', 'user22', 'user23', 'user24'], # 4 users
    'C': ['user41', 'user42', 'user43'], # 3 users
}

These are the output of my shop, and this is the expected output to be written different files called by 'client_group.txt':
A.txt:
group A has 2 product A, monthly income is 370.
group A has 2 product D, monthly income is 304.
group A has 1 product G, monthly income is 196.

group A total income is 870.

group A has total 5 users, and this is its users:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

B.txt:
group B has 1 product B, monthly income is 215.
group B has 1 product E, monthly income is 110.
group B has 2 product F, monthly income is 560.

group B total income is 885.

group B has total 4 users, and this is its users

user21
user22
user23
user24

C.txt:
group C has 3 product C, monthly income is 495.

group C total income is 495.

group C has total 3 users, and this is its users:
user41
user42
user43

This is my current code and I haven't yet reached the expected output (actually currently I don't know how to write to separated files in this case, beside the other issue of my code):
# I added this function, because I had error in the last line of next code block inside the `f-string`, so I thought that could be a workaround for this
def to_join():
    return '\n'.join(client_group_user_counts[user])

for product in products_income:
    for client in client_package:
        for user in client_group_user_counts:
            if product['client_group'] == client['client_group'] == user:
                print(f"""group {product['client_group']} has {product['count']} product {product['product']}, monthly income is {product['monthly_income']}.
total income is {client['total_income']}.
group {product['client_group']} has total {len(client_group_user_counts[user])} users, and this is its users:
{to_join()}
""")

This is current output:
group A has 2 product A, monthly income is 370.
group A total income is 870.
group A has total 5 users, and this is its users:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

group B has 1 product B, monthly income is 215.
group B total income is 885.
group B has total 4 users, and this is its users:
user21
user22
user23
user24

group C has 3 product C, monthly income is 495.
group C total income is 495.
group C has total 3 users, and this is its users:
user41
user42
user43

group A has 2 product D, monthly income is 304.
group A total income is 870.
group A has total 5 users, and this is its users:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

group B has 1 product E, monthly income is 110.
group B total income is 885.
group B has total 4 users, and this is its users:
user21
user22
user23
user24

group B has 2 product F, monthly income is 560.
group B total income is 885.
group B has total 4 users, and this is its users:
user21
user22
user23
user24

group A has 1 product G, monthly income is 196.
group A total income is 870.
group A has total 5 users, and this is its users:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5


open all files needed, put them in a dict on the required key, pass that dict to the function as argument and use the file= argument of the print statement to redirect to a file

Use SQL for this kind of problems (e.g. sqlite)

@rioV8 thanks, yes I also thought of like {name': 'my_expected_output\nanother_output\n_last_output', but I didn't know how to do that.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly thanks, that's a good idea, but I think that's an extra thing for things like this. But I have some plans to learn for this in the future.

@Saeed actually SQL is for this kind of things. Learning basics will take a few hours for you and you will be in next level. Start with sqlite for simple usecases.

Since results are aggregated by "group id", you want to iterate over client_group_user_counts first. This will also allow you to open() a file specific to the current "group id"
This could use some refactoring, but it should give you an idea
Given:
products_income = [
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 2, 'product': 'A', 'monthly_income': 370},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 1, 'product': 'B', 'monthly_income': 215},
    {'client_group': 'C', 'count': 3, 'product': 'C', 'monthly_income': 495},
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 2, 'product': 'D', 'monthly_income': 304},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 1, 'product': 'E', 'monthly_income': 110},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'count': 2, 'product': 'F', 'monthly_income': 560},
    {'client_group': 'A', 'count': 1, 'product': 'G', 'monthly_income': 196},
    ]

client_package = [
    {'client_group': 'A', 'total_income': 870},
    {'client_group': 'B', 'total_income': 885},
    {'client_group': 'C', 'total_income': 495}
]

client_group_user_counts = {
    'A': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5'], # 5 users
    'B': ['user21', 'user22', 'user23', 'user24'], # 4 users
    'C': ['user41', 'user42', 'user43'], # 3 users
}

Try:
for group_key, group_users in client_group_user_counts.items():
    packages = [row for row in client_package if row["client_group"] == group_key]
    products = [row for row in products_income if row["client_group"] == group_key]
    with open(f"{group_key}.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as file_out:
        for product in products:
            file_out.write(f"group {group_key} has {product['count']} product {product['product']}, monthly income is {product['monthly_income']}.\n")
        file_out.write("\n")
        file_out.write(f"group {group_key} total income is {packages[0]['total_income']}.\n")
        file_out.write("\n")
        file_out.write(f"group {group_key} has total {len(group_users)} users, and this is its users:\n")
        for user in group_users:
            file_out.write(f"{user}\n")


Just a quick note, this solution has a quadratic complexity, for each client_group you will have to loop again over all items in each dictionary.

@mozway Sure, if this was something that looked my like a performance challenge rather than an assignment then an alternate approach might be appropriate. I would probably start by reshaping each of the lists into a dictionary based on the key as you did as well.

I would first rework the dictionaries to avoid lopping over them later.
Then loop only once over each key and open the file with a with statement:
products = {}
for d in products_income:
    (products
     .setdefault(d['client_group'], []) 
     .append('group {client_group} has {count} product {product}, monthly income is {monthly_income}.'.format(**d))
    )
packages = {}
for d in client_package:
    (packages
     .setdefault(d['client_group'], []) 
     .append('group {client_group} total income is {total_income}.'.format(**d))
    )

for group, users in client_group_user_counts.items():
    with open(f'{group}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(products[group])+'\n\n')
        f.write('\n'.join(packages[group])+'\n\n')
        f.write(f'group {group} has total {len(users)} users, and this is its users:\n')
        f.write('\n'.join(users))

Example A.txt:
group A has 2 product A, monthly income is 370.
group A has 2 product D, monthly income is 304.
group A has 1 product G, monthly income is 196.

group A total income is 870.

group A has total 5 users, and this is its users:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5


Here's the logic:
You already have all the group names in client_group_user_counts. We're going to use that to generate a bunch of files. We're also going to map group names to filenames (not exactly required for this program, but it's a good-to-have just in case your logic gets more complex down the road).
Then, we're going to iterate over products_income. We lookup the output filename with the group_name value and write the formatted record.
Once we've written all the records, we'll iterate over client_package to write out the total income. But hang on, we'll reformat that dictionary so that the keys are the group names and the values are the total income - it'll just save us some lookup steps.
Finally, we'll iterate over client_group_user_counts. Since the keys are already group names, we can use those to look up the output file. Then we just need to write the usernames themselves to the output file
Here's the code:
# create all the output files
outfiles = {k: open(f"{k}.txt", 'w') for k in client_group_user_counts}

# turn client_package into a dict for easier access
client_package = {row['client_group']: row['total_income'] for row in client_package}

# write everything to the correct files
for row in products_income:
    cgroup = row['client_group']
    prodCount = row['count']
    prodName = row['product']
    income = row['monthly_income']

    outfile = outfiles[cgroup]
    outfile.write(f"group {cgroup} has {prodCount} product {prodName}, monthly income is {income}.\n")

# add the additional space
for outfile in outfiles.values():
    outfile.write('\n')

# write the total income summary
for group, income in client_package.items():
    outfiles[group].write(f"group {group} total income is {income}.\n\n")

# add the users
for group,users in client_group_user_counts.items():
    outfiles[group].write(f"group {group} has total {len(users)} users, and this is its users:\n")
    for user in users:
        outfiles[group].write(f"{user}\n")

# close the files
for outfile in outfiles.values():
    outfile.close()


I like this strategy and use it quite frequently when writing to files where the "next" row gets written to a particular file based on some criteria. One thing I would recommend is the use of a contextlib.ExitStack() that makes management of opening and closing the files much cleaner IMHO.

@JonSG: Thanks for the ExitStack reference #TIL

I don't know if I understand the structure of your program or not, if I'm wrong, coorect my. Since you have the groups in client_group_user_counts you can get all groups from its keys.
groups = client_group_user_counts.keys()

Now that you have all the groups, you can iterate over groups and print what you mentioned above.
for group in groups :
    for product in products_income:
        if product['client_group']==group:
            print(f"group {group} has {product['count']} product {product['product']}, monthly income is {product['monthly_income']}.")
    for package in client_package:
        if package['client_group']==group:
            print(f"group {group} total income is {package['total_income']}.")
    print(f"group {group} has total {len(client_group_user_counts[group])} users, and this is its users:")
    print('\n'.join(client_group_user_counts[group]))
    print()

But generally it is recommended to use libraries like pandas to do more complex tasks.
